# $\text{rank}(AB^2)=\text{rank}(AB)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A$ and $B$ be real $n×n$ matrices such that $$AB=BA,~~\text{rank}(A^2)=\text{rank}(A),~~\text{rank} (B^2)=\text{rank}(B)$$

Show that: $$\text{rank}(AB^2)=\text{rank}(AB)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Sylvester Theory:
$$
Rank(AB^{2}) = Rank(B^{2}) - dim(Im(B^{2}) \cap Ker(A) )
$$
and 
$$
Im(B^{2}) = Im(B)
$$
since 
$$
Rank(B^{2}) = Rank(B)  
$$

Hence ,we can obtain 
\begin{array}
  RRank(AB^{2}) &=& Rank(B^{2}) - dim(Im(B^{2}) \cap Ker(A) )\\
                &=& Rank(B) - dim(Im(B) \cap Ker(A))\\
                &=& Rank(AB)
\end{array}
From the above process,we can see that you have given much more conditions with the redundant terms
$$
Rank(A^{2}) = Rank(A) \quad AB = BA
$$

Answer (score 11):

Let $V =\mathbb{R}^n$ denote the underlying space, so that $A, B:V \to V$. The spaces $B(V)$ and $B^2(V)\subset B(V)$ have the same dimension and are thus equal. Hence
$$AB^2(V) = A(B^2(V)) = A(B(V)) = AB(V).$$
Taking dimensions gives the result.

Comment: Have all assumptions been used?

Comment: Why should they be?

Comment: Hi @anomaly, how do we know that  the image $B^2(V)$ is contained in $B(V)$?  Is this sort of like the Fitting Decomposition theorem?  E.g., the range of higher powers of B can only be smaller, up until the point it stabilizes - and then the chain of kernels of B also stabilize.  This is something I learned in finite-dimensional linear algbera.  Just wanted to know your thoughts; very cool proof, btw.  Thanks,

Comment: $B(V)\subset V$, so $B^2(V) \subset B(V)$.